# making of simple quiz in which user can skip question

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make simple quiz with skip question, means user have right to skip question if he is not sure. In my code there are 4 question's option when I skip the question's option then not showing the answer. But when I attempt all questions its showing answer. please suggest me how to do this.......

```js
function result() {
  var x1 = document.querySelector('input[name="Q1"]:checked').value;
  var x2 = document.querySelector('input[name="Q2"]:checked').value;
  var x3 = document.querySelector('input[name="Q3"]:checked').value;
  var x4 = document.querySelector('input[name="Q4"]:checked').value;
  var result = parseInt(x1) + parseInt(x2) + parseInt(x3) + parseInt(x4);
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = result;

}
```

```html
<h4>Q1</h4>
<label for="A1">A</label><input type="radio" name='Q1' id="A1" value="4">
<label for="A1">B</label><input type="radio" name='Q1' id="A1" value="-1">
<label for="A1">C</label><input type="radio" name='Q1' id="A1" value="-1">
<label for="A1">D</label><input type="radio" name='Q1' id="A1" value="-1"><br>
<h4>Q2</h4>
<label for="A1">A</label><input type="radio" name='Q2' id="A1" value="4">
<label for="A1">B</label><input type="radio" name='Q2' id="A1" value="-1">
<label for="A1">C</label><input type="radio" name='Q2' id="A1" value="-1">
<label for="A1">D</label><input type="radio" name='Q2' id="A1" value="-1"><br>
<h4>Q3</h4>
<label for="A1">A</label><input type="radio" name='Q3' id="A1" value="4">
<label for="A1">B</label><input type="radio" name='Q3' id="A1" value="-1">
<label for="A1">C</label><input type="radio" name='Q3' id="A1" value="-1">
<label for="A1">D</label><input type="radio" name='Q3' id="A1" value="-1"><br>
<h4>Q4</h4>
<label for="A1">A</label><input type="radio" name='Q4' id="A1" value="4">
<label for="A1">B</label><input type="radio" name='Q4' id="A1" value="-1">
<label for="A1">C</label><input type="radio" name='Q4' id="A1" value="-1">
<label for="A1">D</label><input type="radio" name='Q4' id="A1" value="-1"><br>



<h1>Your Score is <span id="score">__</span></h1>
<button type="submit" onclick="result()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Note: element `id`s must be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails because it tries to access the value of a non-selected field.

You can use the new [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?` which will return null if the selector returns nothing

PS: You need unique IDs or just wrap the label around the radio

I give 0 points if not answered. Change to -1 if you wish

PPS: Added a more streamlined map and reduce

```js
function result() {
  var x1 = document.querySelector('input[name="Q1"]:checked')?.value || 0;
  var x2 = document.querySelector('input[name="Q2"]:checked')?.value || 0;
  var x3 = document.querySelector('input[name="Q3"]:checked')?.value || 0;
  var x4 = document.querySelector('input[name="Q4"]:checked')?.value || 0;
  var result = parseInt(x1) + parseInt(x2) + parseInt(x3) + parseInt(x4);
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = result;

  // alternative

  const res = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name^=Q]:checked')]
    .map(inp => +inp.value);
  const score = res.length ? res.reduce((a, b) => a + b) : 0
  console.log(score)
}
```

```html
<h4>Q1</h4>
<label>A<input type="radio" name='Q1' id="A1" value="4"></label>
<label>B<input type="radio" name='Q1' id="A2" value="-1"></label>
<label>C<input type="radio" name='Q1' id="A3" value="-1"></label>
<label>D<input type="radio" name='Q1' id="A4" value="-1"></label><br>
<h4>Q2</h4>
<label>A<input type="radio" name='Q2' id="A5" value="4"></label>
<label>B<input type="radio" name='Q2' id="A6" value="-1"></label>
<label>C<input type="radio" name='Q2' id="A7" value="-1"></label>
<label>D<input type="radio" name='Q2' id="A8" value="-1"></label><br>
<h4>Q3</h4>
<label>A<input type="radio" name='Q3' id="A9" value="4"></label>
<label>B<input type="radio" name='Q3' id="A10" value="-1"></label>
<label>C<input type="radio" name='Q3' id="A11" value="-1"></label>
<label>D<input type="radio" name='Q3' id="A12" value="-1"></label><br>
<h4>Q4</h4>
<label>A<input type="radio" name='Q4' id="A13" value="4"></label>
<label>B<input type="radio" name='Q4' id="A14" value="-1"></label>
<label>C<input type="radio" name='Q4' id="A15" value="-1"></label>
<label>D<input type="radio" name='Q4' id="A16" value="-1"></label><br>



<h1>Your Score is <span id="score">__</span></h1>
<button type="submit" onclick="result()">Submit</button>
```